# SQL Server 2008 Express to SQLite

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

Can I convert a SQL Server Express 2008 database to SQLite?

My database is simple and only has 1 table but it has about 1000 rows and it's hard for me to make a new SQLite database and add these 1000 records.

thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: [Convert SQL Server DB to SQLite DB](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/convsqlservertosqlite.aspx)

It is a free .net converter on CodeProject, the poster stated:

> I needed to convert the existing SQL server databases to SQLite
>   databases as part of a DB migration program and did not find any
>   decent free converter to do the job.

So I assume he has spent some time looking for what you seek and did not have any luck either.

The source code is available and well documented (according to the poster).

Answer (score 0):

There are many software that can generate the inserts code. For example:

[Sql Workbench](http://www.sql-workbench.net/) (free)

[Aqua Data Studio](http://www.aquafold.com/) (non free but you can evaluate)

Both can generate inserts from many different databases including SQL Server.